# Cauchy sequence proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $0<r<1,M>0,$ and suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence such that , for all $n∈N, |a_{n+1}-a_n |≤Mr^n$. Prove that $a_n$ is Cauchy.

I know that I need to show for all $ε>0$, there exists an $N>0$, such that for all $m,n>N$, such that $|a_m-a_n|<ε$.

Should I let $m=n+1$, then show that $ε>Mr^n$ ? If so, how could I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not sufficient (from the definition alone) to do the case $m = n+1$.

Try the following:

Come up with an upper bound for $|a_{n+2}-a_n|$

$\begin{align*}|a_{n+2}-a_n| &= |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - a_n|\\ &\leq |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| + |a_{n+1} - a_n|\\ &\leq Mr^{n+1} + Mr^n\\ &= Mr^n(r+1)\end{align*}$

Come up with an upper bound for $|a_{n+3}-a_n|$

Come up with an upper bound for $|a_m - a_n|$

Once you've done this, you need to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$, $Mr^n < \varepsilon$ (or some variant thereof). To argue this, try taking the natural log of both sides and isolate $n$.

Edit: One final hint: doing the problem this way, you will run into a geometric series. Remember you (should) know how to find the sum of such a series.

Edit #2: As shown in the comments, one has $|a_{m} - a_n| \leq Mr^n(r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1)$. All that remains is to show that this term heads to zero as $n,m \rightarrow \infty$. In other words, for all $\varepsilon > 0$ find $N > 0$ such that for all $n,m > N$, we have $Mr^n(r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1) < \varepsilon$.

Taking the natural log of both sides gives $$ln(\varepsilon) > \ln(M) + \ln(r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1) + n\ln(r)$$
and rearranging terms $$n > \cfrac{\ln\left(\cfrac{\varepsilon}{M(r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1)}\right)}{\ln(r)}$$
Note here that the inequality sign has flipped (why?).

Finally, we would be done if the RHS of this inequality didn't depend on $n$ and $m$. So we need to make an estimation for $r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1$. Remembering that we are allowed to make the RHS larger and not smaller, this means that we want to make $r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1$ larger in the estimation (why?). So the final question becomes:

What can we replace $r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1$ with? The answer: $$r^{m-n-1} + \dots + 1 \leq \sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

Comment: I do as you said and got $|a_{n+1}-a_n |≤|a_{n+1} |-|a_n |$, $|a_{n+2}-a_n |≤|a_{n+2}|-|a_n |$, $|a_{n+3}-a_n |≤|a_{n+3} |-|a_n |$, $|a_m-a_n |≤|a_m |-|a_n |$ but I still don't see how this works.

Comment: Unfortunately you are not applying the triangle inequality appropriately. Indeed, even for $|a-b|$ the best upper bound one can get is $|a| + |b|$, not minus. However, this bound is terrible and we can do better. I've edited my answer to show you the first one, see if you can get the other two.

Comment: I did as you said and got $$\begin{align}|a_{n+3}-a_n|&=|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}+a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}-a_n|\\ &≤|a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}|+|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}|+|a_{n+1}-a_n|\\ &≤Mr^{n+2}+Mr^{n+1}+Mr^n=Mr^n (r^2+r+1)\end{align}$$ and $$\begin{align}|a_m-a_n|&=|a_m-a_{m-1}+a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}+⋯+a_{n+1}-a_n |\\ &≤|a_m-a_{m-1}|+⋯+|a_{n+1}-a_n|\\ &≤Mr^{m-1}+Mr^{m-2}+⋯+Mr^n=Mr^n (r^{m-n-1}+⋯+1),\end{align}$$ I also isolating the $n$, and got $n<ln⁡(ε-Mr)$ but I don't see how this can help my argument, because $|a_m -a_n|<Mr^{m-1}+Mr^{m-2}+⋯+Mr^n=Mr^n (r^{m-n-1}+⋯+1)$ not just $Mr^n$.

Comment: To write exponents, surround the powers with { and }, so for example r^{m-1}. If you can, click ``edit'' on my answer above an take a look at my latex.

Comment: You are correct, $|a_m-a_n|$ has the upper bound $Mr^n(r^{m-n-1} + \dots + r + 1)$. This is why I wrote (or some variant thereof) in my answer. Now we want to show that this goes to zero an $n,m \rightarrow \infty$ (with the appropriate formal definition of course!). Try this first for just $Mr^n$ as a warm-up. Then to finish the proof, we need to do something with the $r^{m-n-1} + \dots r + 1$ term. The very last line of my answer suggests what to do with it. If you still have trouble, let me know and I'll give more help.

Comment: I tried to Isolate for $n$, but the best I can do is get $n<log_Mr⁡〖ε/((r^{m-n-1}+⋯+1) )〗$

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect, it appears as if you are not using logs/inequalities correctly. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif: I have tried to fix some of the LaTeX in two of your comments above.  I don't think the content has changed, but you might want to look them over and be certain.

Answer (score 0):

For any $n\geq0$ and any $p\geq1$ one has
$$|a_{n+p}-a_n|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}|a_{n+k+1}-a_{n+k}|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}M r^{n+k}\leq{Mr^n\over 1-r}\ .\tag{1}$$
Let an $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} r^n=0$ there is an $n_0$ such that the right hand side of $(1)$ is $<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_0$. It follows that $|a_m-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $m>n>n_0$; therefore the given sequence is a Cauchy sequence.